# How can I redirect from View to controller method that has to return another view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view that contains a button which on click has to redirect to method in the controller that returns another view. The thing is that this method accepts arguments and I don't know exactly how to pass them se every time I click the button it redirects correctly?

The method:

```
public virtual ActionResult Classificate (int firstArg, int secondArg)
        {
            //Some logics
            return View(MVC.Document.Views.MyView, model: result);
        }
```

html:

```
<div id="my-button-id">Button</>
```

and in the view's html I want to be able to write a js code that on every **"#my-button-id"** click redirects with 2 parameters that I pass to the function to the method in the controller.

pseudecode:

```
$("#my-button-id").on('click',function(){
    redirectToOtherView(4, 5)
});

function redirectToOtherView(fArg, sArg){
    //this function to redirect to the Classificate method in the Document controller
    //by passing the arguments
}
```

Comment: You want to load the view using ajax or normal page refresh/redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `pass the parameter as query string for GET request` and normal page redirect

```
function redirectToOtherView(fArg, sArg){   

 var queryString="firstArg="+fArg+"&secondArg=sArg";

 window.location.href="/ControllerName/Classificate/?"+queryString

}
```

For ajax GET

```
$.get(url, {firstArg:fArg, secondArg:sArg}, 
    function(result){
    $('#container').html(result);
    }
);
```

or ajax POST --> In Controller add [HttpPost]

```
$.post(url, {firstArg:fArg, secondArg:sArg}, 
    function(result){
        $('#container').html(result);
    }
);
```

Comment: This one seems to work, but I read on the i-net that it is not supported in some browsers older versions, like IE 6. What do you think about that ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik, What feature is not supported? can you paste the link?

Comment: just the window.loacation.href. Do you know how I could do that with ajax call somehow because I tried to do the $.ajax{} but it didn't work.I made the method in the controller [HttpGet] but it just was not redirecting to the view.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik, ajax will never do redirection. it will load only data from server using javascript. it will not do any redirection